# Ajax Call Response Not Being Displayed

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I am trying to dynamically populate a select field in a form with an ajax request to my php based app. The code below shows the ajax request from the view / form javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var clientDropDown = {
            load: function()
            {
                $.ajax({
                    'type': "post",
                    'url': "http://localhost/promptMe/index.php/main/fetchNames",
                    'data': "client",
                    'delay': 5000,
                    'success': function(result)
                    {
                        clientDropDown.attach(result);
                    },
                    'error': function()
                    {
                        alert("There's a problem!");
                    }
                });
            },
            attach: function(result)
            {
                result = $.parseJSON(result);
                $.each(result,function(id,obj){
                    var client = document.createElement('option');
                    client.setAttribute('value',obj.name);
                    client.text = obj.name;
                    $('select#client_name')[0].add(client);
                });
            }
    };
    clientDropDown.load();

});
```

The function handling this request in my controller is shown below

```
function fetchNames()
    {
        $entity_type = $this->input->post('data');
        $names = $this->model1->getEntityNames($entity_type);
        print json_encode($names);
    }
```

From the chrome browser developer tools I see a successful response with the json object at the top of a rendered view and none of the "names" are appended to my select element in my html which has the snippet below

```
<form method="post" action="receiveEntry" class="form">
<fieldset>
    <legend class="content-header">
        Job Details
    </legend>
    <div class="form-content">
        <div class="form">
            <label for="date">Date</label>
            <input type="date" placeholder="Job Date" id="date" name="date" title="Date Job was prepared" />
        </div>
        <div class="form">
            <label for="client_name">Client Name</label>
            <select name="client_name" id="client_name">

            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form">
            <label for="description">Description</label>
            <textarea id="description" name="description" title="Description of Estimated Job" cols="40" rows="5" title="Description of job">Job Description</textarea>
        </div>....lots of other unnecessary form fields</fieldset></form>
```

I am using jQuery1.7.2.

Please can you tell me why I cannot get my select field populated with the returned json object's elements

Comment: What is `$('select#client_name')[0].add(client);` supposed to do? DOM elements don't have an `add` method.

Comment: Why not use jQuery `$("select#client_name").append()` to add options?

Comment: `'success'` and `'error'` are not strings, so take the `'` off.

Comment: @developerwjk That's fine. Object properties can optionally be written with quotes around them.

Comment: @Barmar I saw this from w3schools for the add element (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_select_add.asp).

Comment: I didn't know about that. It's specific to `<select>` elements.

Comment: In that case, I'm not sure why your original code isn't working. Are you sure the returned JSON is what you're expecting?

Comment: Please add `console.log(result)` to the question.

Comment: Since $('select#client_name') is a jQuery collection, not an array, you should use $('select#client_name').get(0).

Comment: @Barmar when I use developer tools on chrome and I look at the network response to my Ajax request, I see the raw json object on top of the rendered html view. The issue I am having is getting it to the select field

Comment: @bobdye jQuery collections are array-like, and `[n]` is equivalent to `.get(n)`.

Comment: @UncleT Please post the raw JSON, you may not be accessing it correctly.

Comment: @Barmar heres the raw JSON  `[{"name":"Lunix Photo's "},{"name":"Luden International"},{"name":"Gorgon Trucks"}]`

Comment: Your code works for me on jsfiddle. I had to remove `JSON.parse()`, because the server sends `Content-type: application/json`, so jQuery parses it automatically. http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/Lyffo28n/6/ Maybe your controller is doing that as well. If you use `dataType: "json"`, jQuery will parse it automatically with or without the header.

Comment: Thank @Barmar. It was something else completely. I customized my view so it renders the reply erroneously